# Append properties to Swagger $ref

Tags: swagger-2.0

Hi guys I'm trying to append a new properties to a reference object but I can't seem to find the correct answer here's what I'm trying to achieve and the result should be something like below

```
{
  "results": {         
     "param1": "Add",
     "param2": {},
     "object1": "obj",
     "object2": "object"
  }
 }
```

So below is what I did

```
responses:
    results:
        description: My description here
        schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Success'
definitions:
    Success:
       properties:
          param1:
            type: string
            default: Add
          param2:
            type: object
          $ref: '#/definitions/ObjectData'
    ObjectData:
       properties:
          object1:
             type: string
             default: obj
          object2:
             type: string
             default: object
```

Comment: @Helen thanks for this. This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do that result this would be my approach

```
resoponses:
    result:
    description: Description here
    schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Success'
properties:
Success:
    param1:
        type: string
        default: 'Add'
    param2:
        type: object
        properties:
            object1: 
                $ref: '#/definitions/object1'
            object2: 
                $ref: '#/definitions/object2'
```